# VBA calculating with strings

Tags: arrays, string, vba, matrix, calculation

I am quite new to vba coding. I have written a code which reads some data generates a matrix and a vector inverts the matrix and then multiples the inverted matrix with the vector, so nothing big. But now I want that the elements of the matrix and vector are strings or symbols. I hope that i will be able to get a more general solution. Is this somehow possible? Both objects are arrays.
The stringe i use do not have numerical values. In other words I am looking for a oppertunity to calculat with symbols like an algebra program like mathematica or maxia does.

Comment: You can pass strings to cdbl(), clng(), cdec(), allowing you to convert them to numerical values and perform numerical operations and calculations. Conversely, you can turn numerical values into strings with cstr(). Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Check out the [tour] as well as [mcve] and also [ask].  If necessary, you can [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: I know that thanks, but i wont vba to calculate something like:x *y. My string dont have numerical values. Cdbl(x) would not work, or does it?

Comment: can you show an example with what you would like to see as an output?

Comment: For example one has this matrix M =[a,b;c,d] and this vector v =[e,f]
so the prodct of M *v is vector k [a*e+f*b;c*e+d*f], just a simple matrix operation but with strings, something similar like mathematica or maxima does

Comment: So I am looking for a suitable libary which has matrix functions allowing me to invert and multiply matrixes consisting of strings